# How Can I expose RSS Syndication Feed through WCF Web Service to JQuery client

Tags: rss, feed, syndication

I wanto to build a WCF service that read RSS Syndication Feed (.NET 3.5 SP1). Then I want to consume the wcf service using JQuery in a web client.  Are you asking why I don't directly consume it from the client?  I think that there are some cross domain security issues when the client is located in a defferent domain.  Anyway, if anyone can show me some code examples, I would appreciate it.  If I can do it in the ASP.NET MVC framework, it would be even better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF service will need to output a format readable by your jQuery HTTP request. (XML / JSON)

Then you just call the WCF service using $.get(... and use the results...